# Where is Load method In CI_Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

In system/core/Controller.php I see the following code:

```
public function __construct()
{
    self::$instance =& $this;

    // Assign all the class objects that were instantiated by the
    // bootstrap file (CodeIgniter.php) to local class variables
    // so that CI can run as one big super object.
    foreach (is_loaded() as $var => $class)
    {
        $this->$var =& load_class($class);
    }

    $this->load =& load_class('Loader', 'core');
    $this->load->initialize();
    log_message('info', 'Controller Class Initialized');
}
```

I tried many time to find load method, load_class() ...

```
        $this->load =& load_class('Loader', 'core');
        $this->load->initialize();
```

Where are they?

Comment: Go to `/system/core/Loader.php` and run a search for `public function view(`, `public function library(`, `public function model(`, etc...

Comment: It is not clear for me. I still cannot find the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `load_class()` is defined in `system/core/common.php` which is included in the last line of `index.php` like so

```
require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';
```

`CodeIgniter.php` "bootstraps" the whole framework.

So, by the time a controller constructor runs the function `load_class()` is defined and ready to go to work.

`load_class()` is creating an instance of the Loader class for the controller to use. Loader has many methods. The most common use is to load other framework libraries, models, helpers and views.
For example

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->load->model('your_favorite_model');
$this->load->helper('url');
$this->load->view('welcome_view');
```

Comment: how can I call it without include,require file, or extends class?

Comment: I am not clear what "it" is. What do you want to call?

Comment: As you see in the CI_Controller class, there is no require file, or extends class. How can I use 'load_class()' in CI_Controller?